# Remove rows data frame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which basically looks like that:

```
      'A'
0     12
1     542
2     676
3     854
4     922
5     972
```

The values in the column 'A' are integers. Further I have a list of subset of the values of 'A'. So I have, say, l = [12,676,854] and I want to remove ALL the lines for which df['A'] is equal to any of the values in my list, i.e. `df['A']=12 or df['A']=676 or df['A']=854`. In this case the desirable output would be

```
      'A'
1     542
4     922
5     972
```

A code like

```
for el in l:
   if df=df[df['A']!=el]
```

would work under 'normal' circumstances but the thing is that my dataframe is relatively huge (~4 mln lines) and my list l has 40k elements. So each time I enter the loop I go through the whole data frame which is extremely time inefficient.
Do you have any idea how to do it in a more efficient way?
Ideally, I look for a code which looks like `df=df[df['A']!=el for el in l]` which is of course incorrect.

Comment: You need `print (df[~df.A.isin(l)])`

Comment: It is dupe, so no  answer.